# Custom Content Pane Title

Tags: panels

I created a custom content pane, however, I'm having some issues trying to hide the title on the page and was wondering if anyone knew of a module for this?

Here's the quick breakdown:

I created a new custom content pane:

[image: Custom Content Pane]

Above I have given the custom content pane no title, however, this is how it shows up:

[image: No Title]

I'd really like to make it look more descriptive.

If I add a title it will show on the variants > content page (image below), but unfortunately, it also shows up on the actual page as well.

[image: Test Title]

Live page:

[image]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

[`ctools_custom_content_type_admin_title`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!plugins!content_types!custom!custom.inc/function/ctools_custom_content_type_admin_title/7)

```
/**
 * Callback to provide the administrative title of the custom content.
 */
function ctools_custom_content_type_admin_title($subtype, $conf) {
  $settings = ctools_custom_content_type_get_conf(ctools_custom_content_type_content_type($subtype), $conf);

  $output = t('Custom');
  $title = !empty($settings['admin_title']) ? $settings['admin_title'] : $settings['title'];
  if ($title) {
    if ($settings['custom_type'] != 'fixed') {
      $output = t('Custom: @title', array('@title' => $title));
    }
    else {
      $output = $title;
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

If the admin title is used, and the custom content type is not set to 'fixed' (see [`ctools_custom_content_type_get_conf`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/ctools_custom_content_type_get_conf/7)), it will use your user input admin title for admin display there.